# Chemistry chemical bonding

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

when a chemical bond is formed, does chemical reaction occur? if i have done a coating on metal substrate then how does it adhere to the substrate? If there is a chemical bond then which reaction does takes place?

Comment: Your 2nd & 3rd sentences make this question so broad that I suspect it will be closed. Regarding your first sentence, there are different kinds of bonds, but a chemical reaction is basically just the process of making and breaking bonds. Regarding your second sentence, you will have to specify what kind of coating and preferably what kind of metal to get a good answer. I guess if you are very specific with your second sentence, your third sentence might be answerable. Long story short: provide all the details that you can about what you are interested in, and keep it specific.

Answer (score 1):

If a chemical bond between atoms is split, or newly generated, than there is occurrence of a chemical reaction.  Not all bonds, however, are equal -- covalent bonds differ from hydrogen bonds, for example.

Your question *may* be interpreted as if you were unsure to discern between [physisorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physisorption), the more general, more frequently mechanism of [adsorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsorption), and [chemisorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemisorption) -- where actual bonds between substrate and coating are formed (yet: not necessarily the same bonds in terms of strength as C-C in an alkyl chain, for example).  If so, look at  [self assembled monolayers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-assembled_monolayer) -- it may shed some light on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends about which type of coating you are talking about. Lets say for electroplating a metal with copper, its just a redox reaction which happening inbetween the chosen electrolyte and the metal which is taken at anode i.e. copper. Here after copper oxidises to cu2+ , then goes towards cathode to be reduced and get deposited over your desired metal which is required to be electroplated. But there is no such bond formation between the copper and the metal over which copper is being deposited. ***It is kind of an interlocking within the roughened surface and also it is because cohesive forces between the metal atoms***.

Comment: what about coating by electrophoretic process?? What type of bond between  coating and substrate

Comment: It will be kind of attraction due to charge on the colloidal particles and the oppositely charged electrode or basically columbic forces.

Comment: does that coating adhere for a long time? coz in my case i used electrophoretic method for deposition on metal substrate followed by drying and sintering. but i still have a doubt that, that coating does not adhere good enough and cant  be used for long term.